# How to reuse an alert dialog inside a SwiftUI View?

Tags: swiftui

I want to be able to show an error popup ( `Alert` ) in all my views whenever some error condition occurs.

On the "logic" side this can be done by implementing a `ViewModel` base class containing:

```
    @Published var showError: Bool = false
    @Published var errorMessage: String = ""
```

Any subclass can then set those values if an error occured.

The problem however is on the `View` side. I would need to add the following code to every `View` that can show an alert:

```
        .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showError) {
                return Alert(title: Text("error"), message: Text(viewModel.errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("ok")))
        }
```

Is there a way to not have to copy paste this everywhere? Otherwise if I want to change the `Alert` behaviour I would need to adapt it all over my codebase.

Comment: Attach it in one place to root view and use `alert(item:` variant.